# N random samples from an array in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

is it possible to get n random samples from an array

e.g. a table has two columns, `id` STRING, and `values` ARRAY(STRING)

the resulting array `new_values` ARRAY(STRING) for each id would be of length `N` and consist of random values from the original `values` array ( i.e. values picked at N random offsets in the array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select *, array(
    select value from (
      select value, offset
      from t.values as value with offset
      order by rand() 
      limit 5 -- replace 5 with value of your N
    )
    order by offset
  ) new_values
from your_table t
```